# Microsoft Workflow Foundation - Global Cancellation

Tags: wcf, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, bpmn, cancellation

I have a workflow that has multiple approval steps operationalized as WCF receives.  Throughout the entire workflow process, it should be possible for the submitter of the process that initiated the workflow to cancel the process.

My question is, "Is there a a method for providing one 'cancellation' receive message?"  It looks to me as if the methodology is at every receive wait point, I need to create a Pick structure embedded within a Cancellation Scope, with the pick being a choice between receiving an approve/deny message from the current reviewer OR a cancel message from the submitter.

From a BPMN standpoint, I would not need to model multiple cancellations, but it seems like from WF, I would.

Any constructive suggestions or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I don't know WF but it would be possible by design. The solution I often use in such cases is two parallel path : one for the approval steps, the other for the cancellation receival. The cancel path may go a terminate process event or merge with the other path using a XOR gate as it abort the other path when it's activated. Hope it could help.

Comment: Thanks!  I just came to that realization and was about to post a "nevermind" :-).  Yes, I can place the entire "cancellable" portion of the workflow in a parallel activity within a cancellation scope, with one branch being the main flow and another waiting for the cancellation message.  Too easy and obvious. Clearly brain was tired.  Thank you though!